# C++ object initialisation using braces (syntax)

Tags: c++, syntax

I just came across this line of code:

```
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 0, 255 };
```

It made me wonder why it can be declared like an array. I thought it might've just ment the same as `textColor(255,0,255);` but it didnt work like that when I tried making my own class. Can anyone explain when this type of syntax is used? Where are the parameters going..?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) of a type, most likely a simple struct or class. For example,

```
struct Foo 
{
  int i,j;
  double x,y;
};

int main()
{
  Foo f = {1,2, 3.,4.};
}
```

**Note** since there is some confusion regarding `structs`, the above example would also work with a `class`, which in this case is identical to the `struct`:

```
class Foo 
{
 public:
  int i,j;
  double x,y;
};
```

In C++11 this type of initialization is [extended to non-aggregate types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Uniform_initialization) under certain conditions.

for example

```
std::vector<int> v = {1,2,3,4,5};
```

Comment: Since a class aggegrates data members as well does it mean an object of a class can be initialized the same way?

Comment: @user1534664 yes, if it satisfies the conditions for being an aggregate. In this sense, `struct` and `class` are identical.

Comment: @user1534664 I added some words about aggregate class.

Comment: Cheers mate! I understand this concept now :)

Answer (score 3):

All **aggregates** can be brace-initialized, which initializes each aggregate member with the matching item. If the list contains fewer items than there are aggregate members, the remaining elements are initialized as though from an empty brace list.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I am clearly mistaken on some point. From the standard: _An aggregate is an array or a class (Clause 9) with no user-provided constructors (12.1), no brace-or-equalinitializers
for non-static data members (9.2), no private or protected non-static data members (Clause 11),
no base classes (Clause 10), and no virtual functions (10.3)._ I _think_ the point you were making is that even though it may be a `struct` it could have any of the listed features that prevent it from being an aggregrate?

Comment: Meh.  Aggregates are structs in the usual informal usage.  Sure, you can technically have struct-like `class`es and class-like `struct`s.  But there are also the connotations and reasons we usually choose `class` or `struct` besides the slight technical difference.

Comment: @hmjd `struct` and `class` are the same in this respect. They both can be aggregates, or not. I added a note to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

`SDL_Color` is an *aggregate* (a `struct` with 4 members, in this case).

You can initialize an aggregate (not just an array) using an initializer list.

```
SDL_Color textColor = { 255, 0, 255 };
```

is the same as

```
SDL_Color textColor;
textColor.r = 255;
textColor.g = 0;
textColor.b = 255;
textColor.unused = 0;
```

Comment: I guess you mean 3 members, not 4 :)

Comment: @KirilKirov: Actually, it has 4 members.

Comment: @KirilKirov: No, the 4th is `Uint8 unused`

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad. I thought you're talking in general.